# Quarkus JPA fails validating schema

Tags: java, jpa, quarkus, quarkus-jpa

I'm doing a batch based on Quarkus.

This is my application.properties:

```
# datasource configuration
quarkus.datasource.db-kind = oracle
quarkus.datasource.username = XXX
quarkus.datasource.password = XXX
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url = jdbc:oracle:thin:...

quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.generation=none
quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.default-schema=MYSCHEMA
quarkus.hibernate-orm.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
```

This is MyApp class method, just a trial to check if everything works properly:

```
public class MyApp implements QuarkusApplication {

    @Inject
    Logger logger;

    @Inject
    MyDAO myDAO;

    @Override
    public int run(String... args) {
        logger.info("Do startup logic here");
        logger.info("Printing args...");
        Arrays.stream(args).forEach(logger::info);
        fetch();
        Quarkus.waitForExit();
        return 0;
    }

    @Transactional
    protected void fetch() {
        logger.info("fetching riga ordine...");
        final MyEntity output = myDAO.findById("id");
        logger.info("output: {}", output);
    }
}
```

When I run my application, *fetch()* method works and I can retrieve MyEntity successfully, however I also get this annoying error:

```
2022-01-28 11:24:57,450 ERROR [io.qua.hib.orm.run.sch.SchemaManagementIntegrator] (Hibernate post-boot validation thread for <default>) Failed to validate Schema: Schema-validation: missing table [MY_TABLE]
2022-01-28 11:24:57,782 ERROR [io.qua.hib.orm.run.sch.SchemaManagementIntegrator] (Hibernate post-boot validation thread for <default>) The following SQL may resolve the database issues, as generated by the Hibernate schema migration tool. WARNING: You must manually verify this SQL is correct, this is a best effort guess, do not copy/paste it without verifying that it does what you expect.

create table MY_TABLE...
```

Basically, I can't understand two things:

1. How I turn off schema validation; on persistence.xml I used to set

```
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="none" />
```

but I can't see how to replicate it with quarkus.

2. Despite I correctly set schema on application.properties with

   quarkus.hibernate-orm.database.default-schema=MYSCHEMA

I receive the schema validation error.

The proof is that using @Table annotation with schema="MYSCHEMA" I don't receive this error (however I don't want to stub schema on entity).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To disable the schema validation, set `quarkus.hibernate-orm.validate-in-dev-mode` to `false` in your `application.properties`.